# Whois cli command not returning contact details

Tags: whois

I am using

```
jwhois version 4.0, Copyright (C) 1999-2007
```

to attempt to retrieve the contact details for a domain, however, the contact details do not seem to be listed anymore, I am missing a flag or something, or do they just not include contact details anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest I could get was the -h for HOST flag

```
whois -h whois.godaddy.com jeffreylroberts.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the many online whois tools to compare. Assuming you are on linux or mac, jwhois --help , man jwhois or info jwhois may shed light on flags.